# How would you match a record from a select statement against a string in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to create a statement to check data from a foxpro database against a string in c#

however I can't seem to get it working, would using parameterised queries here help to achieve what I'm trying to do?

```
string PROPCODE = "IMPORT_" + ID;
string leadtenant = clcodet;
using (OleDbCommand tenantpopulation = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT 
    CLCODE, 
    CLCODEDESC 
    FROM CLIENT WHERE PROPCODET = " + PROPCODE, importConnection))
{
    string tenants = "";
    if (@"CLCODE" = leadtenant)
    {
        if (tenants != String.Empty)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

To Clarify, i want to check whether CLCODE, called from tenantpopulation, matches leadtenant, defined elsewhere in the code

Comment: Check it for what?  Exact match?  That one string or the other contains a specified sequence?  What isn't working?

Comment: Your propcode is a string, but you don't have quotes around it in the query. it should be WHERE PROPCODEET = '" + PROPCODE +"'"

Comment: Basically I need to check to see if CLCODE from the oledbcommand, to match up with th estring leadtenant, which is definied as CLCODET, that is also defined elsewhere in the code

Comment: Parameterized Queries are **always** a good idea, IMO.   Besides being a good defense against SQL Injection, it takes care of quoting or not quoting parameter values for you.   As for seeing if the string from the database matches what is defined elsewhere, `==` or `.Equals()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Use parameters, yes, but you also have to actually run the query and get the output. You've specified the command, but have not run it and read it into a Reader here.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others already noted using parameters is the way to go (not only in VFP but any SQL database). They are not only for preventing SQL injection attacks, using parameters the drivers take care of converting into correct string, adding/removing braces, quotes etc.

```
string PROPCODE = "IMPORT_" + ID;
string leadtenant = clcodet;

using (OleDbCommand tenantpopulation = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT
CLCODE
FROM CLIENT WHERE PROPCODET = ?", importConnection))
{
    tenantpopulation.Parameters.AddWithValue("p", PROPCODE);

    // rest of code seem to be meaningless
    // and I didn't see any code where you run your query
    // depending on your requirement, I assume PROPCODET is a primary key?
    // if so then you to do the check you only need to return the CLCODE
    // with ExecuteScalar:

    importConnection.Open();
    var clcode = (string)tenantpopulation.ExecuteScalar();
    importConnection.Close();       

    string tenants = "";

    // in C# equality check is done with == NOT = (assingment)
    if (clcode == leadtenant)
    {
        // tenants is always String.Empty here
        if (tenants != String.Empty)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Have you ever thought, using Tom Brother's LinqToVFP from codeplex? With Linq, you don't need to know these SQL dialects much and instead you use Object query (and intellisense).